# Python print .psl format without quotes and commas

Tags: python, printing, bioinformatics, genetics

I am working on a linux system using python3 with a file in `.psl` format common to genetics.  This is a tab separated file that contains some cells with comma separated values.  An small example file with some of the features of a .psl is below.

input.psl

```
1 2 3 x read1 8,9, 2001,2002,
1 2 3 mt read2 8,9,10 3001,3002,3003
1 2 3 9 read3 8,9,10,11 4001,4002,4003,4004
1 2 3 9 read4 8,9,10,11 4001,4002,4003,4004
```

I need to filter this file to extract only regions of interest.  Here, I extract only rows with a value of 9 in the fourth column.

```
import csv

def read_psl_transcripts():
    psl_transcripts = []
    with open("input.psl") as input_psl:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(input_psl, delimiter='\t')
        for line in input_psl:
        #Extract only rows matching chromosome of interest
        if '9' == line[3]:
            psl_transcripts.append(line)
    return psl_transcripts
```

I then need to be able to print or write these selected lines in a tab delimited format matching the format of the input file with no additional quotes or commas added.  I cant seem to get this part right and additional brackets, quotes and commas are always added.  Below is an attempt using print().

```
outF = open("output.psl", "w")
for line in read_psl_transcripts():
    print(str(line).strip('"\''), sep='\t')
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Below is the desired output.

```
1 2 3 9 read3 8,9,10,11 4001,4002,4003,4004
1 2 3 9 read4 8,9,10,11 4001,4002,4003,4004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to solve you problem with a simple awk statement.

```
awk '$4 == 9' input.pls > output.pls
```

But with python you could solve it like this:

```
write_pls = open("output.pls", "w")

with open("input.pls") as file:
    for line in file:
        splitted_line = line.split()
        if splitted_line[3] == '9':
            out_line = '\t'.join(splitted_line)
            write_pls.write(out_line + "\n")

write_pls.close()
```